# Background shift in Google Chrome when opacity changes on hover

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, background, opacity

I have a hover effect set up with Jquery that changes the opacity of the hovered element. It works fine in all recent browsers, except for Chrome, where it shifts the body elements' background.

Here's the link: http://wrong.ro/tataia/

My work environment is as follows: Google Chrome v18.0.1025.162 / Windows 7 x64.

Is there any workaround for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems to be working here in Chrome.  Can you be more specific about exactly what you do to cause the issue and exactly what code is involved?  Since you're new here, I should tell you that here on stackOverflow people rarely respond to questions where you just say, here's my page - it doesn't work.  Instead, you need to describe EXACTLY what the steps are to make it have a problem, describe exactly what the problem is and then include the relevant code and HTML in your post.

Comment: i can see some shift in bkgrd image if mouse hovers over "#4 februarie 2012" in chrome

Comment: on GC-18.0.1025.165/MacOs all work fine

Comment: @rt2800 - You have to look very closely, because ALL text links will shift the background when hovered over.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I think I was specific enough in my enquiry. I also added in my last edit the version of Chrome I'm using and my OS version, so I think it's all complete now. When I'll find a solution to this, you can be sure I'll add the code snippets too, but right now I'm in a real hurry to get the problem fixed. Anyway, thanks for your tips!

Comment: You will notice that you've gotten no feedback on your existing code.  That's either because nobody else can see the problem on their computer, doesn't know what problem to look for on your site or because you haven't posted any of the code that you're using.  The key to getting an answer here on SO is making it easy for people to see what code you're using and what exactly the problem is that you need help with.

Comment: @jfriend00 - It seems you have an obsession with formalities. However, you didn't really help. (i.e. "It seems to be working here in Chrome.")

Comment: I'm experiencing this on Chrome with a foreground image. It's bizarre and this is two years later. Did you ever figure out any more clues?

Comment: I fixed my issue - answer below

Answer (score 2):

I experienced something very close to this, in my case changing the opacity on hover caused a foreground image element to wiggle. It looks like the particular cause is related to using transform (which I was using). The fix was simple - on the img element in question I added:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

No more wiggle. I'm not familiar with what this actually does, but it didn't have any weird side effects and fixed the problem.

I also saw an alternate solution that I didn't try - apparantly other people have experienced this and fixed it with rotate:

```
-webkit-transform: rotate(0);
-moz-transform: rotate(0);
transform: rotate(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I can finally see the problem in Chrome.  It is very subtle so unless one knows exactly what you're looking for, it's easy to miss.

I'm still working on the rest of the issues, but when I hover over the "stiati ca" logo in the lower middle, I could see the background shift a bit just to the left of the image.

The problem appears to be related to the `background-size` part of your CSS here.  If I remove the `background-size` lines, the problem completely disappears.  I'm not suggesting that's the actual cause of the problem, but that's the first clue.  My guess at this point in the investigation (more coming later on in the answer) is that something in the hover is causing the document size to change which causes the background to rescale and thus shift:

```css
body {
    background: black url('../img/bck.jpg') left top fixed no-repeat;
    moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/bck.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
     filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='../img/bck.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
}
```

Pursuing this further, I find that if I comment out the text-indent line from this block of CSS:

```css
a#stiati_ca{
    display: block; width: 124px; height: 124px;
    xtext-indent: -9999em;
    background: url('../img/stiati_ca.png') no-repeat;
    margin: 88px auto 0;
}
```

Then, the problem completely goes away for hovering over the logo.  Of course, there is some text from your link showing that I guess you didn't want visible, but you can fix the HTML to work differently.  I'd suggest using a link with a fixed size div in it (no text in the link) and then set the background image on the div and not on the link itself.  This is a safer cross browser way to do things anyway and you won't need the text-indent line and the background shifting problem should go away for the logo image.  If you really need the text in the link but don't want it to show, then put it in a span and make the span invisible with `display: none`.  Either way, you should not set the background image on the `<a>`, but rather on an element with the appropriate size inside the link.  This should work better.

I haven't yet figured out why the same problem occurs on the top four images.  I will add to my post if I figure that one out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a very eloquent answer and I appreciate that you put your time to solve this problem. However, I really need the text in the links. Can you give me some reference on your statement "I'd suggest using a link with a fixed size div in it (no text in the link) and then set the background image on the div and not on the link itself. This is a safer cross browser way to do things anyway"?

Comment: Why do you need the text in the links?  It's not visible on the page.

Comment: Web accessibility, e-readers, RSS, SEO would be a few of the reasons.