# Image scale transition causes floated images further on to wobble in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float, css-transitions, css-transforms

My div class `.product` contains a figure floating inline-block with text to the right. This takes the appearance of a series of cells one below the other.

I've had problems with some of the figures further down the page wobbling about slightly when a scale transformation with transition is started on a figure above them in the sequence.

Earlier in the day, I had a similar problem that started directly below a heading and I thought I fixed it by clearing the float both sides of it, but the problem has resurfaced elsewhere and I can't seem to fix it. I've tried adding `overflow: auto;` to fix the float on the containing elements, but to no avail. I also tried clearing the browser cache.

When I remove the lines of code specific to webkit transition, `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out .1s;` and `-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out .1s;`, the knock-on wobble disappears from Chrome, although the transform effect is instant, rather than gradual. I have the effect occurring so fast, it doesn't make a lot of difference, but it looks more refined on IE, Safari, Opera and Firefox, which seem to allow the transition effect without any browser-specific prefix, whereas Chrome doesn't. In non-Chrome browsers, the image undergoing transition still seems to shift slightly as the transition takes effect, but images further on in the sequence have ceased to wobble. With transition turned off in Chrome, there is no hint of a wobble as an image scales, although it may be too quick for the human eye to spot I guess.

I've reached a state where the results are adequate, but I'd be interested to know if anyone can cast any light on these issues.

```
p, li, ol, ul, {font-adjustment:0.5em;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {font-family: 'umbrageregular' sans-serif;}

h1 {font-size:2em; text-align: center; }
h2 {margin:.5em .1em .1em 1em; font-size:1.4em;}
h3 {font-size:1.2em;}

footer, section {width: 970px; clear: both;}
div.leftNavBar, div.pageContent {float: left;}
div.leftNavBar {width: 400px; } 
div.pageContent {width: 570px; } 
div.product {
       display:inline-block; 
       overflow: hidden; 
       margin: .5em 0 .5em 0;
       background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1); } 
div.product:hover {
       background-color: 
       rgba(0,0,0,.2); 
       -webkit-transition: background-color .2s ease;
       transition: background-color .2s ease; }
div.product p {margin: 0 0.6em .7em 0; }
div.product h3, h4 {margin:0.5em 1.5em .2em 0; text-align:right;}    

figure {margin: .6em .9em .6em .6em; display:inline-block; float:left;
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.9);
        transform: scale(0.9);
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out .1s;
        transition: transform .2s ease-in-out .2s;}

figure:hover {margin: .6em .9em .6em .6em;
       -webkit-transform: scale(1);
       transform: scale(1);
       -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in-out .1s;
       transition: transform .2s ease-in-out .2s;}
```

Comment: I notice this problem specific to Chrome has been reported to Google by @user1680488 http://stackoverflow.com/a/12478692/3119410